# How do i pass NULL to the foreign function with argument of type char*?

Tags: haskell, ffi, c2hs

I'm writing Haskell bindings to some C project and there is a function of type

```
void foo(char *);
```

The problem is that `foo` checks this pointer for `NULL` value and do something different from normal behavior. In my Haskell source wrapper for this function have type `foo :: String -> IO ()` and using `newCString` inside to marshal it's argument.

I wonder how do i give user ability pass `NULL` there? I've been expecting that `newCString ""` would give me `0` since `"" /= "\0"`, but that's not the case.

The only way i see for now is to use "" as indicator that user wants `NULL`, but that seems hackish. I'm expecting that this problem is quite common, but didn't found a question on SO.

Comment: "...since "" /= "\0",..." In C, one is `char s[1] = {0};`, the other `char t[2] = {0,0};`. Both are empty strings as far as the string handling functions are concerned, neither is `NULL`.

Comment: Never thought `String`s are stored with 0-terminator in Haskell. This makes sence then.

Comment: No, not in Haskell, but if you make a `CString` from them (which you'd have to, to pass it to C), a 0-terminator is appended. Anyway, the main point is that an empty string is something different from `NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change your function to

```
foo :: Maybe String -> IO ()
```

And then for `Nothing` send a `nullPtr` to your C function.

Comment: This way is absolutely right from logical POV, but using `Just "blabla"` all over the code would irritate user as much as using `newCString` and `nullPtr` directly.

Comment: @arrowdodger Then write `foo'` which uses your original definition and allow users to use both.

Comment: @arrowdodger Your objection could be dealt with by defining a custom type such as `data NullStr = Null | Str String` and specifying an `IsString` instance for it. You could then use the `OverloadedStrings` extension to have GHC automatically convert literals such as "blabla" to `Str "blabla"` for you.